# Dynamodb putItem constraint based on number of items already existing with same partition key, but different sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table with a partition key and a sort key. We want to limit the number of items (say, 5 max) that can be created under same partition key (but different sort key). What is the best way to accomplish this? Is there a way to add a constraint to the ddb table, so that a putItem request will fail if there is already 5 existing items with same partition key (but different sort key) in table?

One way I can think of is doing a ddb.query with partition key to get a count of all items with same partition key before calling putItem.

Answer (score 1):

Querying and then updating can lead to concurrency issues, where two threads acquire the same value and both create new item, exceeding the limit.

Your use case is better served with DynamoDB transactions. Keep a count item for each partition key:

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | COUNT | 3 |
| 123 | ABC | DATA |
| 123 | DEF | DATA |
| 123 | GHI | DATA |

#### TRANSACTION

- Item 1: The new item (PutItem)
- Item 2: Condition on count item cound value < 5 (UpdateItem)